# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'vectorizer' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

can someone help me find the error in the following code: **UnboundLocalError: local variable 'vectorizer' referenced before assignment**

```
def ngrams(data, labels, ntrain, mn=1, mx=1, nm=500, binary = False,
       donorm = False, stopwords = False, verbose = True, analyzer_char = False):

f = data
if donorm:
    f = normalize(f)

ftrain = f[:ntrain]
ftest  = f[ntrain:]
y_train = labels[:ntrain]

t0 = time()
analyzer_type = 'word'
if analyzer_char:
    analyzer_type = 'char'

if binary:
    vectorizer = CountVectorizer(max_n=mx,min_n=mn,binary=True)

elif stopwords:
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_n=mx,min_n=mn,stop_words='english',
                                 analyzer=analyzer_type,sublinear_tf=True)

if verbose:
    print ("extracting ngrams... where n is [%d,%d]" % (mn,mx))

X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(ftrain)
X_test = vectorizer.transform(ftest)
```

**
Any suggestion is appreciated, thanks guys!**

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include which line the error was thrown at? Including the full stack trace would also be helpful :-)

Comment: From a glance it looks like if `binary` and `stopwords` are both false, `vectorizer` will be undefined. Although, the code's not indented properly, but you can [edit] to fix it. BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask] if you want advice.

Answer (score 0):

Like what wjandrea said in his comment, if neither `binary` nor `stopwords` are truthy then `vectorizer` won't be initialized. So when you try and call `fit_transform` on it, it blows up with your exception.